# How to use boost::object_pool with std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, visual-studio-2013, unique-ptr

This is a two part question illustrated by the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/pool/object_pool.hpp>

struct Foo {
   Foo(int i) : _i(i) {}
   void* operator new(size_t) = delete; // ***
   int _i;
 };

 using FooHandle = std::unique_ptr<Foo>;

 struct Bar {
    Foo* addFoo(int i) 
    {
      Foo* ptr = new (_fooPool.malloc()) Foo(i);             // 111
      return FooHandle(ptr, 
        &boost::object_pool<Foo,  
         boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete>::destroy); // 222
    }
    boost::object_pool<Foo> _fooPool;
 };
```

I am trying to ensure that

1. objects of type Foo are allocated and owned only by objects of type Bar,
2. they are stored in pools, and
3. they are accessed via unique pointers.

Using the Visual Studio compiler I run into following problems

1. If I delete the default operator new (line marked with ***) then placement new (line marked with 111) does not compile. Am I doing something wrong or is it a VS limitation?
2. I imagine that in order to make a proper unique_ptr that was allocated in a pool I need to supply access to the pool deleter. The line marked as 222 is my attempt to do just that. The compiler does not accept it either. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: A custom deleter for a `unique_ptr` has to be declared as a template parameter as well as used in the constructor (unlike for a `shared_ptr`); so you need something like `using FooHandle = std::unique_ptr<Foo, decltype( &boost::object_pool<Foo,  
         boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete>::destroy )>`.

Comment: Also your `addFoo` function needs to return a `FooHandle`, rather than a raw pointer, otherwise the object will be destroyed as soon as the function returns.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan Potter. Of course you are right and addFoo has to return FooHandle. I tried to do that but lost finishing touches while straggling with other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`boost::object_pool::destroy`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/object_pool.html#id376765-bb) is a non-`static` member function, so it needs to be invoked on an `object_pool` instance. Furthermore, the deleter is a part of a `unique_ptr`'s type, so your `FooHandle` alias must be declared accordingly. Also, your `addFoo()` function is returning a `Foo*` when it should be returning a `FooHandle` instead.

```
using FooHandle = std::unique_ptr<Foo, std::function<void(Foo *)>>;

FooHandle addFoo(int i) 
{
  Foo* ptr = new (_fooPool.malloc()) Foo(i);
  return FooHandle(ptr, std::bind(&boost::object_pool<Foo>::destroy,
                                  &_fooPool, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

The problem with the `new` expression is that your `delete`d `new` overload is hiding the global placement `new` operator. The code compiles if you also overload the placement version.

```
static void* operator new(size_t count, void *p)
{
    return ::operator new(count, p);
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25a8c0afcdffe469)

Alternatively, explicitly call the global `operator new`

```
Foo* ptr = ::new (_fooPool.malloc()) Foo(i);
```

Are you sure you want to bother with the deleted `new` overload? Doing that doesn't stop someone from using `::new Foo(10)` to allocate a `Foo` outside of your object pool.

---

As T.C. mentions in the comments, using `std::function` to package the deleter is far from ideal. One way to avoid this is to create a functor type that stores a reference to the `object_pool` instance, and then calls `destroy` on that instance.

```
struct FooDeleter
{
    FooDeleter(boost::object_pool<Foo>& pool)
    : pool(&pool)
    {}

    void operator()(Foo *p)
    {
        pool->destroy(p);
    }
    boost::object_pool<Foo> *pool;
};

using FooHandle = std::unique_ptr<Foo, FooDeleter>;

FooHandle addFoo(int i) 
{
  Foo* ptr = _fooPool.malloc();
  if(ptr)
  {
      return FooHandle(::new (ptr) Foo(i), FooDeleter(_fooPool));
  }
  else
  {
      return FooHandle(nullptr, FooDeleter(_fooPool)); // or throw exception etc
  }
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/151f85f9a1e692ac)

Comment: `std::function` isn't a good choice for `unique_ptr`'s deleter; its constructor can throw.

Comment: @T.C. Agreed, I don't like that either. The only other option I could think of was to create my own functor that took a `boost::object_pool<Foo>&` constructor argument. Is there another option I'm missing?

Comment: `boost::object_pool::malloc` returns `nullptr` on failure;  `::new (nullptr) Foo(...)` has undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks all. I should be able to cook what I need from these suggestions. 

I did realize that I needed to use destroy of a particular pool. However my naive attempts to return FooHandle(ptr, &_fooPool.destroy) wouldn't compile either and I did not figure to use std::bind().

I deleted non-placement new in order to prevent accidental creation of Foo on the heap by people who don't understand the overall intent. Didn't take into account that there is a global new workaround though. This probably still serve my purpose because I mostly try to prevent accidents, not stop a determined hacker.